# Extract substring from string if it matches an element present in the list

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I want to extract a part of the string if the matching element is present in the list for example I have a string `s` and list `l1`:

```
s = 'Vipul Singh, Jun 24, 1995'
l1 = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

Now I want to extract the substring of string s from `'Jun 24, 1995'` since 'Jun' is present in list `l1`.

So this is how I want my substring to be, I tried many `regex`, `str` functions but no result.

Note: I have many string of similar type as

```
vipul singh, Jan 1, 2017, 10:00,
ANI,May 6, 2009, 14:59 IST,
```

Comment: It looks like you just want to extract dates, is that correct?

Comment: I don't think this dupe target will help the OP. Although it seems like he wants to extract dates, that's not explicitly stated in the problem. The more general question (which is also probably a dupe) is how to I search for a pattern that contains a one of the strings in a list.

Comment: @chrisz, Yes I just want to extract dates from the overall string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need to extract the dates, and since they share a common format, this is an easy problem for regular expressions.

Try using [`[a-zA-Z]{3}\s[0-9]{1,2},\s[0-9]{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/cGaC4y/1)

```
s = """
Vipul Singh, Jun 24, 1995
vipul singh, Jan 1, 2017, 10:00,
ANI,May 6, 2009, 14:59 IST,
"""
import re
dates = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]{3}\s[0-9]{1,2},\s[0-9]{4}', s)

print(dates)
```

Output:

```
['Jun 24, 1995', 'Jan 1, 2017', 'May 6, 2009']
```

If you are concerned about matching something like `'ABC 23, 1111'`, you could only accept valid months as the first 3 letters:

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
dates = re.findall(r'(?:{})\s[0-9]{{1,2}},\s[0-9]{{4}}'.format('|'.join(months)), s)
```

Comment: This would match any three character word, not just valid months. You could do `pattern = "|".join(map(lambda x: x + r" \d{1,2}, \d{4}", l1))`

Comment: @pault Added a solution for that case.

Comment: Thank @chrisz this what i want